# Mapbox load local style.json

Tags: node.js, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to load mapbox style from local but it fail. I used code as below:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk...';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
.setView([4.609278084409835, 107.75390625], 5);
L.mapbox.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/style.json',{
  attribution: 'Ifos'
}).addTo(map);
```

it result undefined URL in my app
[image]

Comment: you cannot use a local style json for a leaflet map because Mapbox uses the static maps api (https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles) to generate raster tiles for use in leaflet. you can use a local style if you're using mapbox-gl-js to generate your map though.